# Why if $f_{n}:\, X\to[-\infty,\infty]$ are measurable and $f_{n}\to f$ then $f$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am going over my notebook in real analysis, and there is a conclusion
that states the following:

> Let $X$ be a measurable space, and let $$f_{n}:\,
>  X\to[-\infty,\infty]$$ be measurable functions. Assume that $f_{n}\to
>  f$ then $f$ is also measurable.

This was a conclusion to the statement that claims that (in the same
notation and setting) $\inf$$f_{n}$, $\sup$$f_{n}$, $\limsup$
$f_{n}$, $\liminf$ $f_{n}$ are measurable.

I don't understand how this claim follows, or have any other thoughts
about how to prove this claim, can someone please help me out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f_n \to f$ then $\lim \sup f_n = f$.